How to querySelector from another HTML file other than 'document'?
This code:
 const mobileNavShow = document.querySelector('.mobile-nav-show');

only looks through the index.html of my project, while my navbar is in navbar.html and is out of the scope of querySelector. I used w3's w3-include-html to link the two. If I copy the contents of navbar.html into the body of index.html, my navbar works as intended. I am unsure of the technical terms of the problem I am facing.
I tried to create a navbar in a separate HTML file, but js "document.querySelector('X')" is unable to find elements in the other HTML file.

Do you use  for link navbar?

What is w3-include-html? That doesn't seem to be a standard thing. Generally there is no thing as "files" in JavaScript in browsers.

@RoToRa I found "include html" in w3 school, and since it is fairly easy rather than changing everything to php, I just ended up using that.

it seems unhealthy, you want to steal information from a foreign HTML page, so it's piracy!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You need to wait until these html file are loaded and [w3-include-html]s' innerHTML are replaced.
Use Promise.all() to load and replace innerHTM, put your main js code (ex:  const mobileNavShow = document.querySelector... ) in main.js, import it after Promise.all().
<div w3-include-html="h1.html"></div>
<div w3-include-html="content.html"></div>
<div w3-include-html="content2.html"></div>
<script>
    const getHTML = async (elem, file) => {
        const html = await fetch(file).then(res => res.ok ? res.text() : 'Page not found')
        elem.innerHTML = html
        elem.removeAttribute('w3-include-html')
    }
    const includeHTML = async () => {
        const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll('[w3-include-html]')].map(elem => ({ elem, file: elem.getAttribute("w3-include-html"), }))
        await Promise.all(elements.map(({ elem, file }) => getHTML(elem, file)))
        import('./main.js')
    }
    includeHTML();
</script>

main.js
console.log(document.querySelector("h1"));

h1.html
<h1>abc</h1>

